# Is there an equivalent phrase to "A Child Made in God's Image" in Islam?

Tags: baby, scripture, tradition

I am friends with a Muslim couple who are having a baby. I wrote a song to dedicate to the child in celebration of its upcoming birth. I know roughly what sentiment I want to give for the title of my song.

I am not religious. But I am drawing from what I know. In Christianity, the phrase "A Child Made in God's Image" would be appropriate for my song because Christians believe all men and women are made in God's image. And something that is created in the image of God is pure, holy, and sacred.

I would like to find an equivalent phrase in Arabic that carries the same kind of sentiment in Islam.

## My Question

Can someone provide me with such a phrase to title my song?

Comment: Should the phrase be in Arabic? Or are you looking for a translation of something similar (if appropriate) from Arabic? please explain!

Comment: Yes, the phrase should be in Arabic. I do not need a translation necessarily. I need something that is similar in sentiment. Since Islam and Christianity are different religions, it seems unlikely this phrasing would carry the same significance in Islam as Christianity. For example, Peace and Blessings Upon Him is a phrase that carries weight in Islam. And, u could in principle use it as a Christian, but it would not carry the same significance. So I want a phrase that has this kind of uniqueness within Islam but the sentiment of what I am trying to say.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out what kind of tag i could add to your Question therefore i needed some feedback, as baby is a bit empty... but at the moment i still got no clue!

Comment: How about these ? I added two

Comment: Ok let's see what will happen. Good luck!